# VBA - Search & Replace offsetted value

Tags: excel, vba, search, replace, offset

Getting desperate here. Have an afternoon to finish this and I can't quite figure out what is causing the issue here.

I have a worksheet of Data, and on this sheet has A list of people, the systems they use, their username, their managers etc. This data is taken from an external file that in sometimes out of date, so I am writing a macro that will manually override outdated data (such as their manager)

This extracted data is on a worksheet called "Extract".

I have another worksheet called "Data", and in this worksheet I have two tables; Name on System - **"NoS"** - and Override Manager Name - **"OMN"**. These tables are adjacent to each other. The idea is that my macro will search for a name on **NoS**, and if it finds it then it will replace their manager (which is 7 cells to the right) with the value in the adjacent cell in **"OWN"**

***N.B. I am using tables/named ranges so that when names are added the range is dynamically updated on VBA***

At the moment, when I run the Macro it is changing the names ofpeoples managers, however it is also changing the values of other cells on other rows (even if the persons name in "Extract" isn't on "NoS". My code, and some of my data is below, does anyone know what is causing the issue and how I can fix it?

```
Dim c, exceptionNames, extractNames, FoundOne As Range
Set exceptionNames = Range("NoS")
Set extractNames = Worksheets("Extract").Range("A1:I200")
    For Each c In exceptionNames
        With extractNames
            Set FoundOne = .Find(What:=c, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Not FoundOne Is Nothing Then
                extractNames.Replace What:=FoundOne.Offset(0, 7), Replacement:=c.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
            End If
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

"Data" Tab

**Name on System   |     Override Manager Name**

Don Donaldson    |     New Manager

Aaron Aaronson   |     New Manager 2

David Davidson   |     New Manager 3

"Extract" Tab

**Full Name  | First Name  | Last Name |  Department |  Username  | System  | Date  |   Manager   Access**

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense. Let me know if you need me to explain something in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that I am misunderstanding your intent here, but I would just use a `VLOOKUP` formula in column 8 on sheet 'Extract'.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Extract!A1,NameAndManager,2,FALSE)), "manager not found",VLOOKUP(Extract!A1,NameAndManager,2,FALSE))
```

Combine NoS and OMN into one range, NameAndManager.

You can just copy that formula to all the cells in the 'Manager Access' column.

If you don't want "manager not found" to appear, and you want it to leave the existing name unchanged, just put this formula into a new column and have it default to "" if the name is not found.  Then you can do a simple `IF` formula to create a new column with all the correct manager names.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is to suggest you to try to run your sub with F8 key to see which way your code is executed. This should help.

However, I think (but I'm not sure as I can't check it) you need to add:

```
   Set FoundOne = Nothing
```

just after `.Replace` method but within `If Not FoundOne Is Nothing Then` structure.

You can also consider using `Exit For` to exit your loop if appropriate.

Moreover, it's difficult to suggest something for sure if we can't see your data. Especially it's risky to use `.Find method` with `LookAt:=xlPart parameter`.